# .emacs file evaluation in a new frame

Tags: emacs

When I open a new frame in emacs, none of the settings in my .emacs file are evaluated unless I open the file and evaluate the buffer manually.  Is there a secret that I am missing?  Some bit of magic in my .emacs file that should handle this?

Comment: the .emacs is only evaluated once when Emacs start. So all configuration there should apply to all frame. That said there are things that only apply to the initial frame.

If you could be more specific on what is not set in the new frame.

Comment: i'm primarily concerned with the color schemes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define colors in all emacs frame, one can change the default face:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black")
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :foreground "gray90")
```

Or use default-frame-alist:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
  '((foreground-color . "gray90")
    (background-color . "black")))
```

I've both in my .emacs, and there could be a reason...